# How to upload the images from salesforce to Google Drive using visual force page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to upload the images from salesforce to Google Drive using visual force page?i need to upload the images  from local system to google drive using input file in visualforce page.can anybody help me about to upload the images from visualforce page to Google drive.

Controller:

```
public class GoogleDriveController{
    //Fetched from URL
    private String code ;
    public blob file { get; set; }
   // public String type{get; set;}
    public String filetype{get;set;}
    public  String filename{get; set;}

    private string key = '377203344030-3ckrlt2adh2d99sn************************vj.apps.googleusercontent.com' ;
    private string secret = '*************' ;
    private string redirect_uri = 'https://ap1.salesforce.com/apex/GoogleDrivePage' ;
    private String accesstoken ;
    private  Integer expiresIn ;
    private String tokentype;

    public GoogleDriveController()
    {
        code = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code') ;
        System.debug('----------------------------------------------------------------'+code);
        //Get the access token once we have code
        if(code != '' && code != null)
        {
            AccessToken() ;
        }
    }

    public PageReference DriveAuth()
    {
        //Authenticating
        PageReference pg = new PageReference(GoogleDriveAuthUri (key , redirect_uri)) ;
        return pg ;
    }

    public String GoogleDriveAuthUri(String Clientkey,String redirect_uri)
    {
        String key = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(Clientkey,'UTF-8');
        String uri = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(redirect_uri,'UTF-8');
        String authuri = '';
        authuri = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?'+
        'client_id='+key+
        '&response_type=code'+
        '&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'+
        '&redirect_uri='+uri+
        '&state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://oa2cb.example.com/myHome&'+
        '&login_hint=jsmith@example.com&'+
        'access_type=offline';
        return authuri;
    }
    public  PageReference UploadFile()
    {


      System.debug('----------------fn---------------'+filename);
      System.debug('----------------ft---------------'+filetype);
      System.debug('------------------at-------------'+accessToken);
       //String parent_id = '1121945745';
        String boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
        String delimiter = '\r\n--' + boundary +'\r\n';
        String close_delim = '\r\n--' + boundary + '--';
        String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file);
       System.debug('--------------be-----------------'+bodyEncoded);

        String body=
        delimiter +
       'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' + 
       '{ "title" : "'+ filename+'",' +
        ' "mimeType" : "'+ filetype+ '" }'  + 
        delimiter +
       'Content-Type: ' + filetype + '\r\n' +
       'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
       '\r\n' +
        bodyEncoded +
        close_delim;

        System.debug('--------body is-------------'+body);




    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files');

    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer' +accessToken);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/mixed; boundary="'+boundary+'"'); 
    req.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueOf(body.length()));
    req.setHeader('Content-Encoding','base64');
    req.setBody(body);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setTimeout(60*1000);
    // Http http = new Http();
    // HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
     HttpResponse res = null;
     http h= new Http();
     res= h.send(req);
     System.debug('---------------------'+res.getbody());
     return null;

    //string sUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com';
    //req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
    // req.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueof(req.getBodyAsBlob().size()));
    // req.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueof(body.length()));
    //req.setTimeout(60000); 
    //  req.setHeader('Content-Encoding','base64');
    }

    public void AccessToken()
    {
        //Getting access token from google
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
        req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        String messageBody = 'code='+code+'&client_id='+key+'&client_secret='+secret+'&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri+'&grant_type=authorization_code';

        req.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueOf(messageBody.length()));
        req.setBody(messageBody);
        req.setTimeout(60*1000);


        Http h = new Http();
        String resp;
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        resp = res.getBody();




        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(resp);
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME)){
        String fieldName = parser.getText();
        parser.nextToken();
        if(fieldName == 'access_token')
        {
            accesstoken = parser.getText();
        } 
        else if(fieldName == 'expires_in')
        {
            expiresIn = parser.getIntegerValue();
        }
        else if(fieldname=='token_type')
        {
            tokentype=parser.getText();
        }
        }
  }   
        System.debug(' You can parse the response to get the access token ::: ' + resp);
  }
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="GoogleDriveController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:commandbutton action="{!DriveAuth}" value="Google Drive Authentication" >
             <!-- <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}"  id="file"/>-->
    </apex:commandbutton></apex:pageblock>

    <apex:inputfile value="{!file}" contentType="{!filetype}"  filename="{!filename}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Upload fiel" action="{!UploadFile}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: can you see my update code Tushar Sharma.i tried that code,but its not working

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your String body variable and incorrect setEnpoint, use below code for uploadfile method

```
    public void uploadFile(){
    if(file != null)
    {
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        String boundary = '----------------------------314159265358979323846';
        String delimiter = '\r\n--' + boundary + '\r\n';
        String closeDelimiter = '\r\n--' + boundary + '--';   

        //Converts a Blob to an unencoded String representing its normal form
        String encodedFile = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file);
        String body = delimiter + 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n{ "title" : "' + filename + '", "mimeType" : "' + filetype + '" }' + delimiter +
                    'Content-Type: ' + filetype + '\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n' + encodedFile + closeDelimiter;

        //set methods into req to upload file
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
        req.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueOf(body.length()));
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"');
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart');  

        req.setBody(body);       
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setTimeout(60*1000);
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

        //Fill blank 
        file = null;
        filetype='';
        filename=''; 
    }      
}



 <apex:page controller="GoogleDriveController">
 <apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:commandbutton action="{!DriveAuth}" value="Google Drive Authentication" >
         <!-- <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}"  id="file"/>-->
            </apex:commandbutton></apex:pageblock>

        <apex:inputfile value="{!file}" contentType="{!filetype}"  filename="{!filename}"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Upload fiel" action="{!UploadFile}"/>
 </apex:form>
```